# Type Error when using " ..." % (...) type of string

Tags: python, django, string, typeerror

I'm having a problem when trying to process a form in Django. The lines that are causing me trouble are the **form.cleaned_data** ones.

```
   Message.objects.create(
                    object=_("Changement de profil - %s %s (%s) ") % (self.request.user.first_name,
                                                                      self.request.user.last_name,
                                                                      self.request.user.pk),
                    author=self.request.user,
                    receiver=admin,
                    content=_("Bonjour, voici les nouvelles informations concernant mon profil :\n"
                              "- %s\n"
                              "- %s\n"
                              "- %s\n"
                              "- %s\n") % (form.cleaned_data["nom"],
                                           form.cleaned_data["prenom"],
                                           form.cleaned_data["telephone"],
                                           form.cleaned_data["adresse"],
                                           #   str(form.cleaned_data["reaffectation"]) if form.cleaned_data["reaffectation"] != None else _("Aucune reaffectation")
                                           )
                )
```

It's giving me this error:

> 'object' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

However, when I checked the type of each element, it's saying that they are of type **str**. My initial thought was that the reverse_lasy (aka: _) was returning a different object and thus causing this error.

I tried to change the cleaned data to a normal string and it didn't work either.

The "**object**" kwargs isn't causing any trouble even though this is the same syntax so I'm kind of lost.

**Edit 1 :**

Response : Object kwarg was causing a keyword conflict with python syntax

Comment: The method `create` doesn't take `object` as a parameter. It's nothing to do with the strings or formatting

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Are you talking about the **object** keyword arg or the **objects** before the create. If it's the **object** kwarg , then I should add that it is a CharField in model.

Comment: It's the `object` not the `objects` that's the problem. I don't know django, but I've just had a brief look at the docs. I doubt it's python on it's own that's disallowing `object` as a kwarg, more the way django is designed (not saying django should allow `object` as a kwarg) e.g. `def f(**k): print(k['object']); f(object=1)` works fine, and is slightly humorous

Comment: see above link re clash of `object` as both a CharField and a python reserved word